# two decimal places in MySQL but it shows error at the word SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, decimal

hi can anyone help me on how to execute the "NEW-BONUS" column with two decimal places? i tried cast, round, truncate and decimal but it shows error at the word SELECT

```
SELECT LASTNAME, EDLEVEL,
SALARY+1200 AS "NEW-SALARY",
BONUS*0.5 AS "NEW-BONUS"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EDLEVEL = 18 OR EDLEVEL = 20
ORDER BY EDLEVEL DESC, 3
```

Comment: Do you want to SALARY+1200? and BONUS*0.5?

Comment: yea but the NEW-SALARY column is already on two decimal places because SALARY is an existing column. the NEW-BONUS is generated from SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **"TRUNCATE"**

So please update your query like this

```
SELECT LASTNAME, EDLEVEL,
(123+1200) AS "NEW-SALARY",
TRUNCATE((111*0.5),2) AS "NEW-BONUS"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EDLEVEL = 18 OR EDLEVEL = 20
ORDER BY EDLEVEL DESC, 3
```

**123** is demo value and **111** is also demo value